# Looking to create a non-linear phase portrait of an "Elliptical Spiral"

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I am looking to find an equation that will plot what i like to call an elliptical spiral. But i do not know where to begin. What i mean by an elliptical spiral is this:

You take a point on the y-axis and that is at the point $(0,1)$. You then draw a quarter of an ellipse down to a point $(\frac{1}{2},0)$. The next points would be $(0,-\frac{1}{4})$,$(\frac{-1}{8},0)$,$(0,\frac{1}{16})$,$\cdots$ you continue to do this untill up until infinite. The rate of change that $r$ changes as it goes from point to point would be $2^{-n}$ where $n$ is the number of times you hit each axis.

I am a bit new to the phase portrait side of differential equations so how exactly would i go about defining my idea better? How would i go about finding these equations?

Comment: "you continue to do this untill up until infinite" - so for instance, the next point is $(0, -1/4)$? Otherwise, your rule is unclear...

Comment: Yes that is correct, sorry

Comment: So, tell us, what you really want: a system of ODEs that produces such curves or parametric equation for any of them?

Comment: @Evgeny Either is fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the following figure:

[image]

I just took the parametric representation of a standard logarithmic spiral and stretched by different factors in $x$- and $y$-direction. Note that the curve so produced is $C^\infty$ all the way, whereas your proposal leads to "kinks" every quarter turn. (Of course you can adapt the values of the parameters $a$, $b$, $c$ to your liking.)

Comment: This is about as good as it gets haha thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

A centered ellipse with axis $a$ and $b$ has an implicit equation

$$\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}=1,$$

anda parametric equation

$$x=a\cos(t),y=b\sin(t).$$

You need to take one of these, choose the axis lengths (like $(1,\frac12$) then $(\frac12,\frac14)\cdots$) and quadrant (like $x\ge0\land y\ge0$ or $0\le t\le\frac\pi2$, then $x\ge0\land y\le0$ or $-\frac\pi2\le t\le 0\cdots$), and repeat.

Not sure that this is what you really want, as it has no direct connection with familiar differential equations.

Answer (score 0):

Working with Blatter's figure, it's apparent that this is a stretched logarithmic spiral. We can the (normal) logarithmic spiral in complex coordinates as

$$z=e^{(c+i)\theta}$$

Then the solution you want is

$$x=a\Re\{z\}, \ \ \ y=b\Im\{z\}$$

Notice that the rings grow further apart. If you want evenly spaced rings you can use Archimedes spiral,

$$z=\theta e^{i\theta}$$

or for rings that get closer together, Fermat's spiral

$$z=\sqrt{\theta} e^{i\theta}$$

Any of these will produce nice elliptical spirals.

Answer (score 0):

I was working on the simulation of spiral galaxy shapes using the inverse square, then looked into a spiral equation for comparison. The algorithm below gives you an ellipse using both methods and with little more adjustment(in kb below) can produce two coinciding ellipses. I am looking into the analytic reason for this;
%comparing the Inv square with the golden(logarithmic) spiral, EQ; r=a^(2*th/pi), where a=constant; .
% Inv square; a=k/r^2; v0 given, start from r0=1, th0=0.
clear all; close all;
nk=110;nkv=1:nk; dth=1; th=dth*2*pi*(nkv-1)/(nk-1); dt=.01;a=2; kb=-6.9*1e2; vx=4; vy=-34;
rs=a.^(2*th/pi); xs=rs.*cos(th); ys=-rs.*sin(th); figure(1);plot(xs,ys,'o-r');grid on;hold on;
x=xs(1);y=ys(1);
for kk=1:nk; r=sqrt(x^2+y^2);r3=r^3; ax=kb*x/r3; ay=kb*y/r3;
vx=vx+ax*dt; vy=vy+ay*dt;  x=x+vx*dt;y=y+vy*dt;
X(kk)=x; Y(kk)=y; end;'kk';
plot(X,Y,'-k ');grid on; hold on;plot(0,0,'sr');

Comment: This is more phyisics